# Does the liberated human (Jivan Mukta) has the same knowledge as brahman?

Tags: brahman, moksha

If a person's soul get liberate(Jivan Mukta) and alive, then does his knowledge is equal to the knowledge of brahman?

Comment: Individuality doesn't remain after the knowledge of Brahman so such question cannot exist.

Comment: Consider the case of a person got liberate but is living in human body in his last life...

Comment: One gets knowledge of Brahman when one's Kundalini reaches Sahasrara, then alone one goes into Nirvikalpa Samadhi, i.e Advaita state. Normal jivas cannot keep their bodies for more than 21 days after Samadhi, Isvarakotis (incarnations) can, their Kundalini comes back to lower plane where they can communicate with world.

Comment: Moksha means one merges with Brahmn...hence no separate existence..then how this Q???

Comment: @YDS some are in final life with liberated soul... I'm asking about them...

Comment: you mentioned "a person got moksha"..it implies that u are asking about someone who already got Moksha...but as per ur comment it seems you are asking about Adikarikas..is that correct?? if so answer should be NO in my opinion...but you should rephrase the Q as of now it really looks unclear...

Comment: Jivan Mukta becomes completely absorbed in Brahman whereby "he doesnt know anything" but he becomes himself book of knowledge as he is absorbed in Brahman always!

Comment: Once the Jivan realizes Brahman, the mind ceases to exit which means he doesnt know but he himself becomes everything!

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria "doesn't remain after the knowledge of Brahman"...what does that mean, we have Brahmn Rishis right????

Comment: @AkshayS No, if he is every thing then how comes he does not know any thing.

Comment: @hanugm The difference is in the false"he" and real "he" that's the Sukshuma. You dont know anything but you are everything which means you dont operate from mind but from the pure consciousness

Comment: @YDS The state of Nirguna Brahman (i.e knowledge of Brahman) is only perceived when one's Kundalini reaches Sahasrara. Brahma Rishis and others come back to lower plane to teach mankind but as long as they communicate, they are not in the highest state because in highest state, one cannot even speak.

Comment: The questiion is meaningless. Brahman is Knowledge itself. No meaning of having same knowledge as Brahman?

Comment: @commonman Is Sri Krishna Brahman or not?

Comment: Sri Krishna is Brahman in Svarupa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if we go by the following [Mundaka Upanishad](https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/mundak/Mundaka_Upanishad.pdf) verse:

> **He who knows the Supreme Brahman becomes Brahman Itself**. In his family none devoid of the Knowledge of Brahman is born. He crosses
>   over sorrow, he crosses over sin. Freed from the knots of the heart he
>   becomes Immortal.
>
> **Verse 3.2.9**

Answer (score 0):

No, I do not think so.

Because, Brahman is different from Ishvara, the All-Knowing Supreme.

Brahman is Existence-Consciousness-Bliss. Brahman is all-pervading. So who will know whom?

The knowledge is possible only when knower and known are different, which is not the case for Brahman.

As the Kenopanishad says

> As Brahman is ear of ears, mind of mind, speech of speech, life of life. the wise men reject the false knwledge of the self (ego) as perceived by the senses and become immortal.
>
> Eyes can not go there, speech can not go there, mind can not go there,None knows Brahman and we do not know how to explain Brahman.He is definitely different from anything that can be known..That what is not expressible by speech but by which speech is expressed, know that is Brahman. That what is worshipped is not Brahman. He who knows Brahman knows that he knows not.He who thinks he knows Brahman does not know Brahman.

So I think all these make my point clear that the question of Brahman's knowledge of anything does not arise.

https://www.swami-krishnananda.org/essay/essay_2.html